# Autoajustar ancho de jqgrid dentro de tab bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, jqgrid

Estoy utilizando [jqgrid](/questions/tagged/jqgrid) dentro de un Tab de [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) y la grilla no se autoajusta al tamaño del Tab, se expande mucho. ¿Existe una forma de hacer que la cuadrícula se ajuste al tamaño máximo del Tab de boostrap?

```
var info = datos; $("#gvsDetalleRevisionErradicar").jqGrid("GridUnload");
            var grid = $("#gvsDetalleRevision").jqGrid({
                datastr: info,
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                height: "300",
                //width: newWidth2,
                rowNum: 1000000,
                multiselect: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                //forceFit: true,
                colNames: ['Siembra', 'Lote', 'Linea', 'Palma', 'Fecha Cuarentena', 'Dias en cuarentena', 'Fecha revision', 'Dias desde revision', 'No veces erradicada', 'No veces revisada'],
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Siembra', name: 'Siembra', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'Lote', name: 'Lote', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'Linea', name: 'Linea', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'Palma', name: 'Palma', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'FechaErradicacion', name: 'FechaErradicacion', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'DiasCuarentena', name: 'DiasCuarentena', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'FechaRevision', name: 'FechaRevision', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'DiasDesdeRevision', name: 'DiasDesdeRevision', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'NoVecesErradicada', name: 'NoVecesErradicada', resizable: false},
                    { label: 'NoVecesRevisada', name: 'NoVecesRevisada', resizable: false}
                ],
                caption: "Listado de palmas en cuarentena",
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    var p = this.p, item = p.data[p._index[id]];
                    if (typeof (item.cb) === "undefined") {
                        item.cb = true;
                    } else {
                        item.cb = !item.cb;
                    }
                },
                onSelectAll: function (id, status) {
                    for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
                        var p = this.p, item = p.data[p._index[id[i]]];
                        item.cb = status;
                    }
                },
                loadComplete: function () {
                    var p = this.p, data = p.data, item, $this = $(this), index = p._index, rowid;
                    for (rowid in index) {
                        if (index.hasOwnProperty(rowid)) {
                            item = data[index[rowid]];
                            if (typeof (item.cb) === "boolean" && item.cb) {
                                $this.jqGrid('setSelection', rowid, false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            });
            jQuery("#gvsDetalleRevision").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
```

Comment: Por favor agrega tu codigo para que sea mas claro lo que preguntas.

Comment: Adicione el código de mi jqgrid

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que jqGrid no es responsive

[Guriddo jqGrid JavaScript 5.0 is released](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1484)

pero si hay una adaptacion que permitiria resolver el problema

veras como define

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="path_to_css_files/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
```

y en la definicion del grid

```
$("#grid").jqGrid( {
   ...
   styleUI : "Bootstrap",
   ...
 });
```

con esto deberias poder hacer responsivo a jqgrid

Tambien podrias evaluar el estilo

[jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/extra.html)

si revisas en los extras veras que define un estilo responsive para el jqgrid.

O sino evaluar alternativas como las mencionadas aqui

[Way to make jqGrid responsive on web browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035296/way-to-make-jqgrid-responsive-on-web-browsers)

Comment: Hola, he adicionada el css con bootstrap y aun no logro hacerla responsive

Comment: revisaste la demo que se propone en el link http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/  y en tu caso aplica de esa misma forma? puede que el css no hay cargado, realiza un Ctrl+F5 y analiza con el developer tools del browser en la solapa network si es que carga este estilo. Recuerda que debes ubicarlo al final despues de la carga de los css de bootstrap

Comment: Si carga el css pero aun sigue sin funcionar, y tambien he refrescado con el Ctrl + F5 y nada :(

Comment: puedes validar que este css lo defines despues de los css que bootstrap ?

Comment: Uso master page y ahi tengo el bootstrap y luego en la página como tal tengo este último css